# GORM withCriteria returns unexpected duplicate results

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have two models `Quiz` and `QuizQuestion` and `Quiz` has `QuizQuestion`s. When I do:

```
QuizQuestion.withCriteria { 
    quiz { 
      eq("id", 107) 
    }
}
```

I get 4 results when my Db shows there are only 3 `QuizQuestion`s in the database for quiz_id 107. Why does this happen?

Comment: Can you please put your domain with relationship here?

Comment: @Abdullah what I meant was it would be great if you post the explanation to your answer instead of referring to an external link..

Comment: I did not do any R&D in this but as now I have sufficient time that is why I am asking for your domain model, so it would be great if you can provide your domain model. Thank you.

Comment: @Abdullah You solution works! That's why I upvoted it. I was just asking for a comprehensive answer here in SO as the link might die in the future. Thanks again!

Comment: Would you like to update your question with dummy domain model, it would be helpful to me to reproduce the situation.Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Just try:

```
setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY) in withCriteria
```

For further info see [blog](https://coderwall.com/p/re1iiq)

Comment: I have stumbled upon this solution. I'm interested in why this is happening.

Comment: I just did. I would be great if you would explain it here as well as the like might be gone :)